# How to download source from google code?

Tags: google-code

feeling like a complete newbie, but I can't figure out how
to download the source code for this project on Google Code:
https://code.google.com/p/xlarge-demos/source/browse/

Please let me know how, maybe a program, or a site that does it, anything works,

Comment: Press the "Checkout" link and it will tell you how to access the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the project doesn't provide a packaged download (and it seems that it doesn't), you need to use a version management system (command-line tool or in an IDE) to check out the code.

In this case, this would be Subversion. The [Checkout](https://code.google.com/p/xlarge-demos/source/checkout) section on the Google Code page shows which command you need to use on the command-line, and a link to installation instructions for Subversion on various platforms.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack-

Just export it to github(option thats found right under the name of the file).Then download it from github as a zip file.

Comment: That doesnt seem to be an option anymore. The export to github' button is there, but it 404s